# check two conditions together in if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
if (!check1() || !check2()) {
    return
}
```

How make check1() and check2() to run together - don't stop on check1() and don't depend on its result?

Comment: Elaborate more!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you're trying to do? If you don't want to depend on `check1()`, then simply use `if (!check2())`

Comment: You want to run `check1()` but don't want to use its result?  It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @David Most likely `check1()` and `check2()` do more that their names suggest and are expected to perform other operations.

Comment: As you may have gathered from the downvotes and other comments, your code creates some ambiguities because it is unknown what `check1()`and `check2()` actually do. It is not clear from your question that you expect more than processing a *check* with a boolean result. Having a method perform other processing than calculating the returned result is considered bad design. If you insist to keep it, you should at least rename your method to `check1AndDoTheOtherThing()` to make it clear what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run the two checks and persist their return values to variables, they're both guaranteed to run. You can then use the results in your `if` condition, like so:

```
var check1 = check1();
var check2 = check2();

if (! check1 || ! check2) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is right, I don't understand why it had 2 downvotes.

Comment: While this is technically correct, the OP should be warned that methods claiming to do a *check* should not have any side responsibilities that require the method to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but force calling functions in if condition by ',' :

```
 var b1 , b2 ;
 if ( (b1=!check1() , b2 = !check2() , b1 || b2 ) ) {
     return
 }
 /*// or
 If ( !( (check1() && true) && (check2() && true) ) ){
     return
 }*/
```